# sql server tables to json using c#

Tags: json, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I want to create one JSON file for the project which has entityframework core. There is a relationship between tables, FK, etc... The reason behind this is I want data from SQL server based on customer subscription and not all the data. SO from query, I can get only those rows which are for specific customers.

I want one JSON file which has data for each table. I want specific data in the JSON file. Using LINQ, I have created query but the problem it returns FK tables information also. I want parent and child tables data separately.

I tried creating SQL query which returns JSON like 
"select * from table FOR JSON AUTO". Problem with this solution is I have to write a query for each tables, no general query is possible. I can write the dynamic query and run it through SP. But entitytframewrok core allows calling SP for each tables only.

```
var roles = service.Roles.Where(o => o.SubscriptionId == null || o.SubscriptionId == subscriptionId).ToList();

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(roles, Formatting.Indented);
```

Here Role has child table RoleClaim which have RoleId as FK, so in JSON response I am getting roleClaim also which I don't want. I want only those columns which are in table.

**Main thing is I don't want to create some class and assign value from DB and then serialize it. I want columns same as in database, so I can compare JSON file on next fetch and able to knew if new columns are added.** 
I want JSON file something like this.

```
{
  "Subscriptions": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "Customer1",
      "Description": null,
      "Order": 0,
      "ParentId": null,
      "LogoId": null,
      "Status": 1
    }
  ],
  "Roles": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "Name": "SuperAdmin",
      "NormalizedName": "SUPERADMIN",
      "ConcurrencyStamp": "2117900a-8ff8-43f0-bc03-4afdae56a233",
      "IsAssignable": false,
      "DefaultForNewUser": false,
      "SubscriptionId": null
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "Name": "User",
      "NormalizedName": "USER",
      "ConcurrencyStamp": "e9578c3a-1b52-46e2-8dd6-c4a475355ff8",
      "IsAssignable": true,
      "DefaultForNewUser": true,
      "SubscriptionId": null
    }
   ],
  "RoleClaims": [
    {
      "Id": 1,
      "RoleId": 3,
      "ClaimType": "ra",
      "ClaimValue": "2_Action"
    },
    {
      "Id": 2,
      "RoleId": 3,
      "ClaimType": "ra",
      "ClaimValue": "2_ArtefactReference"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: you want it to be flat?

Comment: For each table JSON data and all should be combined to one file.

Comment: can you provided the class structures?